# Two IP addresses of one device in local network. How to interpret them?

Tags: c#, networking, ip-address, local-network

I used Bonjour in C# to get IP address of IP camera in the local network. I used `GetAddrInfo(...)` to do so. When the address is found this method is invoked:

```
  private static void eventManager_AddressFound(DNSSDService service, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string hostname, DNSSDAddressFamily addressFamily, string address, uint ttl) {
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(hostname);
        Console.WriteLine(address);
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

    }
```

The output I get is:

```
----------------------------------------
axis-00408cbeeae5.local.
192.168.0.2
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
axis-00408cbeeae5.local.
169.254.44.36
----------------------------------------
```

When I want to connect to the device I use first address. **What is the second address for?**
Also when I run **ipconfig** I see two different ip addresses of my machine. So I see analogy but I do not understand it.

[image]

Comment: You have some seriously funky stuff going on in your IP Configuration.  I suggest you check the advanced configuration settings of that wireless adapter and make sure you don't have multiple IP Addresses defined.  At the very least I would try a reboot to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

That second address looks like one used for autoconfiguration. It should go away once the adapter has been configured. I don't know why it would persist, but then, I don't know about IP cameras.

If the first address works, then just keep using it. Basically, use the first address that works.

Comment: Is it any wise way to decide which is valid -> I mean create automatic mechanism which will decide. Of course I can check if `ip.substring(0,3).equals("192")` but maybe there is something better.

Comment: They are both equally valid. It's literally a question of using the first one you like. Probably the first one that works.

Comment: Yes, the first one works, the second is not. But I wanted to do mechanism which will check it. Maybe pinging the ip?

Comment: Yes only the first one is "pingable" :P, second:request time out.

Comment: Could you look at this stuff, please? You seem to be expierienced in C#. Thank you!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095608/code-starts-only-when-application-run-is-invoked