# Code starts only when Application.Run() is invoked WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a method which is invoked in `class A` and  it is defined in `class B`:

```
class B{
      [STAThread]
        public static void ScanForAxisCameras() {
                DNSSDService service = new DNSSDService();
                DNSSDEventManager eventManager = new DNSSDEventManager();
                eventManager.ServiceFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceFoundEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceFound);
                DNSSDService browse = service.Browse(0, 0, "_axis-video._tcp", null, eventManager);
                Application.Run();//if not invoked everything above does not start
            }
}
```

---

```
class A{ ...before invoking..... B.ScanForAxisCameras(); ....after invoking....}
```

The code in `class B` "starts"/works only if I invoke `Application.Run()`. **But it causes that all the code in `class A`  `....after invoking....` method does not work**. How to handle it so it will not freeze the application?

**Edit:** the `class A` is `class MainWindow.xaml.cs`. It is WPF application.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            createGUI();
        }

        private void createGUI() {

            LocalNetworkScanner.ScanForAxisCameras();//when there is no Application.Run()  ScanForAxisCameras() does not work.
}
}
```

Comment: Is this a winform app, a web application, or what?  Do you already have a message loop started at this point?  Are you starting a message loop later on?

Comment: If you don't call `Run` then the message loop doesn't start so yeah, it makes sense that you don't get any notifications until after you call it.

Comment: @BartoszKP "Events cannot work without an event loop."  That's not true at all.  Most events will never use a message loop.  It's only when the code is trying to marshal to a UI thread (which doesn't even need to be from an event) that this is an issue.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, you're right. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: You most certainly shouldn't be calling `Application.Run` in a WPF application at all.  Either there is a bug in the 3rd party component you're using, it was designed for use only in WinForms, not WPF, or you're not using it correctly somehow.

Comment: @Servy This code in the `class B` always needs that Application.Run(). Maybe I can put it in the other thread?

Comment: @Servy Ok if it was a console application how should I handle it?

Comment: @Yoda I don't know.  My money's still on it being a bug in the 3rd party application, assuming you're not using it incorrectly.  You'd need to find someone familiar with that library; try contacting their support services, if they have any.  The fact that the event isn't firing normally is a problem that they should be able to help you address.

Comment: @Servy Apple is author of that library. it is `Bonjour`. This company does not give ....

Comment: @Servy I would like to rephrase the question but it will be looking dramatically different. I will start new thread and add link here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random behaviour of the WPF application after adding some events before App.Run();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100987/random-behaviour-of-the-wpf-application-after-adding-some-events-before-app-run)

Comment: @Servy, I agree `Application.Run` should not be called at all. I suspect the problem is as trivial as giving the wrong local scope to the objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21109114/1768303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF UI thread on which you call `ScanForAxisCameras()` already has a message loop. I believe the problem with your code is that **all objects** you create inside `ScanForAxisCameras` **have the local scope**:

```
public static void ScanForAxisCameras() {
        DNSSDService service = new DNSSDService();
        DNSSDEventManager eventManager = new DNSSDEventManager();
        eventManager.ServiceFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceFoundEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceFound);
        DNSSDService browse = service.Browse(0, 0, "_axis-video._tcp", null, eventManager);
        Application.Run();//if not invoked everything above does not start
}
```

Without `Application.Run()`, your objects (`service`, `eventManager`, `browse`) may be getting destroyed and finalized as soon as `ScanForAxisCameras` finishes. So, the events you're looking for (like `ServiceFound`) may not even have a chance to get fired.

If you call `Application.Run()`, then `ScanForAxisCameras` doesn't exit (at least not until `Application.Run()` itself exits). That keeps your objects alive and functional.

Try refactoring your code to keep the references to these objects in member fields of your class (or in static variables, FWIW). I believe that should fix the problem.

**[EDITED]** On a side note, the `[STAThread]` attribute doesn't make sense in that context (unless you use `ScanForAxisCameras` as an entry point for a new thread - apparently, that's not the case here).

Comment: That was the case! Is there a place I can more read about that behaviour? To explain it in the thesis?

Comment: @Yoda, glad it helped. Just search the web for something like "C# objects lifetime". E.g: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163316.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Application.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) starts the message loop for that particular thread, if there is no message loop then there is no notification for your objects to know they have to do something.

> The code in class B "starts"/works only if I invoke Application.Run(). **But it causes that all the code in class A ....after invoking.... method does not work**.

`Run` is a blocking call therefore any code after that call is not reachable until the application is closing down i.e. when you exit the message loop.

> How to handle it so it will not freeze the application?

In short, you can't. `Run` will always block so any code you need to run as part of your application startup will have to happen before the call.

---

After your edit to mention that this is a WPF application then `Application.Run` as a `static` method is not the right way to go here. If you need to run initialization when your application starts then you can do what has already been suggested and override the `Run` method of the `Application` class, or alternatively (maybe more appropriately) you can hook into the [OnStartup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup.aspx) event e.g.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // code before startup
        base.OnStartup(e);
        // code after startup
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at the EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a new `Run()`-method in your `App` in the `App.xaml.cs` file.
Here you *can* perform custom actions before the application itself gets initialized.
Further information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public new void Run()
    {
        // Do your stuff here
        B.DoStuff();

        // Call the base method
        base.Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though in this situation you would need to add Application.Run() in a different class. Run() accepts nothing, ApplicationContext, Form. This controls the lifetime of the application and should be called before class A, unless class A is the entry point.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx for details.

Comment: Please look at the EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

A **Windows Forms application** starts when the Main method is called. You can implement initialization procedures on the Main function. However, to initialize a **Windows Forms application** fully and start it routing **Windows Forms events**, you need to invoke Application.Run.

you can read about Application [here](http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/index.php?title=Application_Architecture_in_Windows_Forms_2.0%E2%80%94Application)

Comment: Please look at the EDIT. I should say it is WPF application.

Comment: i don't think there is no difference :)

Comment: @PouyaSamie Well, it makes a *huge* difference.  `Application.Run` is a Winform construct, not a WPF construct, and shouldn't be used in a WPF application.

Comment: @servy that's a load of nonsense, WPF has it's own [Application.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597010(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @James Which is not a static method; it's an instance method.  The OP is calling it from a static context, so he's clearly calling the Winform component.  And through his code it's also clear that he already has a message loop when calling `App.Run`, since he already has shown a window.