# How to define my own main method in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to override orignal main method in WPF.

I want add content at the beginnig of the origina main method.  How to do it?

It seems that it has to be done in `App.xaml.cs` file, but still don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: To add own content at startup you can override [Application.OnStartup Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: what do you want this for? simply override `Application.OnStartup()` in the `App.xaml.cs`, while leaving the `Main()` method alone. A WPF application is not a console application.

Comment: @LPL I want to add my content before: Application.Run() is invoked. If it would work could you show me an example. Tried many things and I am "little" lost. Where I should override it how it should look.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe you can, directly. The designer introduces its own `Main` method.

What you *can* do is create your own separate class with a `Main` method, which in turn calls `App.Main` when you want to:

```
using System;

namespace AppWithCustomMain
{
    class CustomMain
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CustomMain!");
            App.Main();
        }
    }
}
```

Then set the "startup object" build setting in your project properties to `CustomMain`, and it should call your `Main` method first, which in turn calls into `App.Main`.

This is assuming you *really* need to get in before anything else, however. Normally you'd just either subscribe to the [`Application.Startup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, or override [`Application.OnStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) within your `Application` subclass.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you have any bad experiences with overloading the `Run`-method? Was my first thought.

Comment: Is Herdo idea is ok? It worked well and it is solution for this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095608/code-starts-only-when-application-run-is-invoked-wpf-application

Comment: The solution Herdo gave is for this problem. Do you know why it happens?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095608/code-starts-only-when-application-run-is-invoked-wpf-application/21097554#21097554

Comment: @Herdo: Well, I personally think it's less clear - introducing a *new* method which happens to be called by the generated code doesn't seem ideal to me. This isn't really overloading - it's introducing a new method. In particular, if the generated code ever changes the type used to declare the `app` local variable in `Main` from `App` to `Application`, your code would break. You want a custom entry point, and this is what gives you that.

Answer (score 4):

You can introduce a new `Run()`-method in your `App` class (yes, you're right - it has to be done inside the `App.xaml.cs` - , make your stuff and then call the base implementation:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public new void Run()
    {
        // Do your stuff here

        // Call the base method
        base.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post this as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095608/code-starts-only-when-application-run-is-invoked-wpf-application

Comment: This *isn't* overloading - it's introducing a new method declaration with the same signature as an existing one, and it's brittle IMO. The current generated code uses `App app = ...; app.Run();` but if that's ever changed to `Application app = ...; app.Run();` (or something similar) then the code would break very subtly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, my bad. I corrected it to "introducing". You're right. But I'm really sure that Microsoft won't change the application entry point of existing applications at any point in time.
Yoda and his team has to make sure that nobody will change the entry point, yep.

Comment: @Herdo: Yes, I'm reasonably confident that it won't actually break - but I don't like having that sort of brittleness in an app for no particularly good reason. Given that Yoda actually wants a new entry point, why not just do that instead?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really override the main method of the application, if you want to call a specific method when your application starts up, you can override the `OnStartup` method of the `App` class (file `App.xaml.cs`).

Here's an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to add content before `Application.Run()` is invoked. Will that work in that case? How to override it and call the orignal `OnStartup` or  maybe it is undefinded.

Comment: @Yoda please clarify `why` you need to add anything before `Application.Run()`

Comment: @HighCore It is because of `Bonjour` in C# in winForms it will only work if you define `EvenManagers`(from Bonjour) before you call `Application.Run()` I need that in WPF application.

Comment: @Yoda What about using a static constructor?

Comment: @JohnGibb I did not solve my problem..... exceptions TargetInvocationException